# Expanding or collapsing text using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to learn how to use jQuery to expand/collapse text on a webpage but am not sure how to this by using the "a href" links? I'd like the user to expand or collapse text by clicking on the "Show more" links. I know that you have to add or remove the 'hide' class to do this but how exactly would I use the toggle class to achieve this?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 87.5%;
  width: 650px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 15px 25px; 
  border: 3px solid blue;
}
h1 { 
  font-size: 150%;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 120%;
  padding: .25em 0 .25em 25px;
}
div.hide {
  display: none;
}
ul {
  padding-left: 45px;
}
li {
  padding-bottom: .4em;
}
p, a {
  padding-bottom: .4em;
  padding-left: 25px;
}
a, a:focus, a:hover {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="subset_expansion.js"></script>    
</head>

<body>
  <main id="jdom">
    <h1>Expanding and Collapsing messages</h1>
    <h2>Message 1</h2>
    <div>
        <p>Click the link below to expand this message</p>
    </div>
    <div class="hide">
        <p>Hello!</p>
    </div>
    <a href="#">Show more</a>   

    <h2>Message 2</h2>
    <div>
        <p>Click the link below to expand this message</p>
    </div>
    <div class="hide">
      <p>BOOP</p>
    </div>
    <a href="#">Show more</a>

    <h2>Message 3</h2>
    <div>
        <p>Click the link below to expance this message</p>
    </div>
    <div class="hide"> 
      <p>Things to do when you're bored</p>
      <ul>
        <li>Go for a walk</li> 
        <li>Try your hand at painting.</li>
        <li>Listen to music</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <a href="#">Show more</a> 
  </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: And where is your js code?

Comment: There is a `Tidy` button in code editor popup. Please use it.

Comment: Chek my code snippet.  I provided code with shoe more and less functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('a').on( "click", function(){
    $(this).prev("div").toggleClass('hide');
    if($(this).text() == 'Show more')
    {
       $(this).text('Show Less');
    }
    else
    {
       $(this).text('Show more');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
body {
 font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 87.5%;
 width: 650px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 15px 25px; 
 border: 3px solid blue;
}
h1 { 
 font-size: 150%;
}
h2 {
 font-size: 120%;
 padding: .25em 0 .25em 25px;
}
div.hide {
 display: none;
}
ul {
 padding-left: 45px;
}
li {
 padding-bottom: .4em;
}
p, a {
 padding-bottom: .4em;
 padding-left: 25px;
}
a, a:focus, a:hover {
 color: blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>    
</head>

<body>
 <main id="jdom">
  <h1>Expanding and Collapsing messages</h1>
  <h2>Message 1</h2>
  <div>
            <p>Click the link below to expand this message</p>
        </div>
        <div class="hide">
            <p>Hello!</p>
  </div>
  <a href="javasctipt:void();">Show more</a>   
  
  <h2>Message 2</h2>
  <div>
            <p>Click the link below to expand this message</p>
        </div>
        <div class="hide">
   <p>BOOP</p>
  </div>
  <a href="javasctipt:void();">Show more</a>
   
  <h2>Message 3</h2>
  <div>
            <p>Click the link below to expance this message</p>
  </div>
  <div class="hide"> 
   <p>Things to do when you're bored</p>
   <ul>
    <li>Go for a walk</li> 
    <li>Try your hand at painting.</li>
    <li>Listen to music</li>
   </ul>
  </div>
  <a href="javasctipt:void();">Show more</a>    
 
 </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello @MenjiXo
Please check above edited code
i added change text for show more and show less
for more user comfortable

Answer (score 0):

Try the below snippet. Tweak to your requirements. I added a `data-show` attribute tag and then in `onclick` called a function and pass the data to toggle.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 87.5%;
  width: 650px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 15px 25px; 
  border: 3px solid blue;
}
h1 { 
  font-size: 150%;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 120%;
  padding: .25em 0 .25em 25px;
}
div.hide {
  display: none;
}
ul {
  padding-left: 45px;
}
li {
  padding-bottom: .4em;
}
p, a {
  padding-bottom: .4em;
  padding-left: 25px;
}
a, a:focus, a:hover {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="subset_expansion.js"></script>    
</head>

<body>
  <main id="jdom">
    <h1>Expanding and Collapsing messages</h1>
    <h2>Message 1</h2>
    <div>
      <p>Click the link below to expand this message</p>
    </div>
    <div class="hide" data-show="link">
      <p>Hello!</p>
    </div>
    <a href="#" onclick='$("[data-show=link]").toggle()'>Show more</a>   

    <h2>Message 2</h2>
    <div>
      <p>Click the link below to expand this message</p>
    </div>
    <div class="hide">
      <p>BOOP</p>
    </div>
    <a href="#">Show more</a>

    <h2>Message 3</h2>
    <div>
      <p>Click the link below to expance this message</p>
    </div>
    <div class="hide"> 
      <p>Things to do when you're bored</p>
      <ul>
        <li>Go for a walk</li> 
        <li>Try your hand at painting.</li>
        <li>Listen to music</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <a href="#">Show more</a>    

  </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Its a bad practice to write inline click handlers

Comment: @Rajesh Yes. But I gave snippet only to make him understand. It is easy to move to `<script>`

Comment: Its not about easy or difficulty. You are adding answer and remember, people helped by your answer will take this approach as correct approach.

Comment: @Rajesh Thanks.  I had updated my answer.  Consider up voting if it's worth.

Answer (score 0):

Add iquery on link and also add class in link like `show-more` and wrap the message div with parent div like i did `msg-wrap`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.show-more').click(function(){   
    $(this).parents('.msg-wrap').find('.hide').slideToggle();
  })
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 87.5%;
  width: 650px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 15px 25px; 
  border: 3px solid blue;
}
h1 { 
  font-size: 150%;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 120%;
  padding: .25em 0 .25em 25px;
}
div.hide {
  display: none;
}
ul {
  padding-left: 45px;
}
li {
  padding-bottom: .4em;
}
p, a {
  padding-bottom: .4em;
  padding-left: 25px;
}
a, a:focus, a:hover {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="subset_expansion.js"></script>    
</head>

<body>
  <main id="jdom">
    <h1>Expanding and Collapsing messages</h1>
    <div class="msg-wrap">
      <h2>Message 1</h2>
      <div>
          <p>Click the link below to expand this message</p>
      </div>
      <div class="hide">
          <p>Hello!</p>
      </div>
      <a href="#" class="show-more">Show more</a>
    </div>
    <div class="msg-wrap">
      <h2>Message 2</h2>
      <div>
          <p>Click the link below to expand this message</p>
      </div>
      <div class="hide">
        <p>BOOP</p>
      </div>
      <a href="#" class="show-more">Show more</a>
    </div>
    <div class="msg-wrap">
      <h2>Message 3</h2>
      <div>
          <p>Click the link below to expance this message</p>
      </div>
      <div class="hide"> 
        <p>Things to do when you're bored</p>
        <ul>
          <li>Go for a walk</li> 
          <li>Try your hand at painting.</li>
          <li>Listen to music</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <a href="#" class="show-more">Show more</a>
     </div>
  </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
body {
 font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 87.5%;
 width: 650px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 15px 25px; 
 border: 3px solid blue;
}
h1 { 
 font-size: 150%;
}
h2 {
 font-size: 120%;
 padding: .25em 0 .25em 25px;
}
div.hide {
 display: none;
}
ul {
 padding-left: 45px;
}
li {
 padding-bottom: .4em;
}
p, a {
 padding-bottom: .4em;
 padding-left: 25px;
}
a, a:focus, a:hover {
 color: blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="subset_expansion.js"></script>    
</head>

<body>
 <main id="jdom">
  <h1>Expanding and Collapsing messages</h1>
  <h2>Message 1</h2>
  <div>
            <p>Click the link below to expand this message</p>
        </div>
        <div class="hide">
            <p>Hello!</p>
  </div>
  <a href="#" class="show_more">Show more</a>   
  
  <h2>Message 2</h2>
  <div>
            <p>Click the link below to expand this message</p>
        </div>
        <div class="hide">
   <p>BOOP</p>
  </div>
  <a href="#" class="show_more">Show more</a>
   
  <h2>Message 3</h2>
  <div>
            <p>Click the link below to expance this message</p>
  </div>
  <div class="hide"> 
   <p>Things to do when you're bored</p>
   <ul>
    <li>Go for a walk</li> 
    <li>Try your hand at painting.</li>
    <li>Listen to music</li>
   </ul>
  </div>
  <a href="#" class="show_more">Show more</a>    
 
 </main>

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on("click",".show_more",function(){
  $(this).prev().toggle();
  $(this).text(function(i, text){
      return text === "Show more" ? "Show Less" : "Show more";
  })
});

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

$("a.show-more").on("click",function(){

```
    $(this).text(function(i, v){
   return v === 'Show More' ? 'Show Less' : 'Show More'
});
```

});